# How can I speed up with less sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is how I get whole count number, and `@codes` object

```
@codes = user.codes.joins(:community).merge(Community.not_deleted).order("codes.updated_at DESC").limit(10)
@codes_count = user.codes.joins(:community).merge(Community.not_deleted).order("codes.updated_at DESC").count
```

Is there any technique to make this less sql queries?

something like

```
@codes_all = user.codes.joins(:community).merge(Community.not_deleted).order("codes.updated_at DESC")

@codes_count = @codes_all.count
@codes = @codes_all.limit(10)
```

and Is it possible to make this eager loading something like this?

```
@codes_all = user.codes.includes(community: [:country, :language]).joins(:community).merge(Community.not_deleted).order("codes.updated_at DESC")

@codes_count = @codes_all.count
@codes = @codes_all.limit(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear whether you're trying to make the SQL query itself faster, or just reduce the complexity. No matter what you do, you'll still have to make a minimum of two queries. One to get the total count, and one to get 10 codes. There isn't any way around this. In your second example, it's reducing the duplicate code, but it's still going to make the exact same queries as your first example.

In your third example, I would only recommend eager loading the related models if you're actually using them later on. Otherwise, you're just going to be adding overhead that isn't needed.

If you're trying to speed things up, make sure you have database indexes in place for any columns used for sorting or ordering.